# Write summary of fit in pdf file or similar

Tags: r

I'm doing a linear fitting on many datasets in a loop and plotting the results in a pdf file. Is it possible to directly save the output of summary(fit) in the same pdf file instead of observing the summaries of about 100 datasets through the console?

```
  LMmodel <- y ~ x
  fit <- lm(LMmodel, data = Dataset)

  pdf(file = OutputFile, width = 10, height = 6, paper = "a4r")

  xLim = range(x)
  yLim = range(y)

  plot(x, y, type = "p", xlim = xLim, ylim = yLim,
       main = plotTitle, xlab = "x [m]", ylab = "y [dB]",
       pch = 20, cex = .9)
  regLine(fit, col=palette()[2], lwd=2, lty=1)
  grid(lwd = 1.5)

  plot(density(residuals(fit)), main = "Density Plot of the Residuals"))

  dev.off()
  graphics.off()
  return(summary(fit))
```

Comment: The function textplot(capture.output(summary(fit))) of the gtools package did the trick.

Comment: Sounds like you want to generate a report. There are several good tools for that. I recommend [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) but there are also [sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) and [brew](http://www.r-bloggers.com/brew-creating-repetitive-reports/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really recommend [Knitr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/index.html) with [Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) to generate Report.

Here I use you code to generate a pdf in 3 simple steps. I assume you have Rstudio installed.

1. I create a new R sweave file ( using the menu)
2. Where I insert 2 chuncks (using the *Chunks* at right)

   ```
   <<myplot,echo=FALSE,fig=TRUE>>=
   library(car)
   x <- rnorm(n=20,mean=30,sd=20)
   y <- rnorm(n=20,mean=180,sd=10)
   Dataset <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
   LMmodel <- y ~ x
   fit <- lm(LMmodel, data = Dataset)
   xLim = range(x)
   yLim = range(y)
   plot(x, y, type = "p", xlim = xLim, ylim = yLim,
       main = "plotTitle", xlab = "x [m]", ylab = "y [dB]",
       pch = 20, cex = .9)
   regLine(fit, col=palette()[2], lwd=2, lty=1)
   grid(lwd = 1.5)
   plot(density(residuals(fit)), main = "Density Plot of the Residuals")
   @
   ```

the summary is :

```
    <<mysummary>>=
    print(summary(fit))
    @
```

1. You generate a pdf file using the **compile PDF** button.

You can insert what you want between the summary and the plots to build complex reports.

Comment: The '' are not required for the chunk name; however, required for any items, e.g. label="hello".