# write model summary and plot to one pdf in r

Tags: r

My question is how to combine model summary and multiple plots into one pdf file.
This is what I'm trying to do:

```
pdf('model_result.pdf')
print(summary(my.model))
print(plot(my.model))
dev.off()
```

The resulting pdf file only contains the graph. No model summary. Do anyone know how to do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at `rmarkdown`: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_quick_tour.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write summary of fit in pdf file or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194442/write-summary-of-fit-in-pdf-file-or-similar)